# Error installing NLTK Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to install NLTK (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk).  I have Python 3.6 installed on my Windows 10 (64 bit) computer.  When I run the NLTK installer, I get the following error:

"Python version -32 required, which was not found in the registry"

Does anyone have any experience with this or know how to resolve the error?

Comment: Other than installing a 64-bit version or building from source?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I am not aware of a 64bit version but I am new to NLTK.  Could you point me to where that is located?

Comment: @abccd I am not familiar with PIP install.  Could you provide more details?

Comment: @abccd never mind.  Using pip ntlk did it

Comment: Oh well, I'll just leave my answer for future readers I guess

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nltk itself is os independent, but the Windows msi installer is not, it's specifically for 32-bits pythons. Alternatively, you can use pip to install nltk, which will install the os independent source file. Simply in `cmd`, type this:

```
pip3 install nltk
# pip/pip3 doesn't matter only if there's multiple pythons, but if that does not work (command not found) type:
py -3 -m pip install nltk
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:
*py -m pip install nltk*

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and was able to solved my problem:

Windows 10 users with Python 64 bit might encounter a RuntimeError when trying to run import nltk.  A recent Windows 10 update has a known bug when running the most recent version of NumPy 1.19.4 on the Python 64 bit version.

Solution: uninstall NumPy version 1.19.4 and reinstall 1.19.3.

From the command prompt:

pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.3

If you are running a Mac and/or Python 32 bit the import nltk command should work fine.

For more information on the Windows bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html

Best,
Genie

Answer (score 0):

after running
`py -m pip install nltk`   as suggested by Priscilla's comment above

I close my VS code and reopen it and everything is working !

Comment: Yea, may things have changed and problems have been resolved in the versions that came up during the last *four years*...